# Can't login into google account from firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

**This is my firebase init**

Here are my Firebase class to get service from firebase Auth:

```
class FirebaseService {    
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  static const String _GOOGLE_AUTH = "/social-login";
    
  Future<String?> signInWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
      await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
      await googleSignInAccount!.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
      );

      await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      printMe("idtoken ${googleSignInAuthentication.idToken}");
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
      rethrow;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Sign Out method:

```
  Future<void> signOutFromGoogle() async {
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
    await _auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

Here the run log.
[image]

Comment: Any error shows?

Comment: nope! I dont see any error

Comment: When the google dialog pop up i did log in and it just disapear right after, And in my firebase auth store doesn't see any account  LogIn into

Comment: add your sha keys in firebase, hope you got solution!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to answer the question without an error message but here you go

remember to add your SHA keys in firebase.

```dart
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  static const String _GOOGLE_AUTH = "/social-login";

  Future<TPFirebaseUser> signInWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
          idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        );
        final UserCredential authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        return TPFirebaseUser(authResult.user, null, null);
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      return TPFirebaseUser(null, null, error);
    } catch (error) {
      return TPFirebaseUser(null, error.toString(), null);
    }

    return const TPFirebaseUser(null, 'Unknown Google Sign in error', null);
  }
```

```dart
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    try {
      Future.wait([
        _auth.signOut(),
        _googleSignIn.signOut(),
      ]);
    } catch (error) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';


class TPFirebaseUser extends Equatable {
  final User? user;
  final String? error;
  final FirebaseAuthException? authException;

  const TPFirebaseUser(this.user, this.error, this.authException);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [user, error, authException];
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answered, but i have already at sha1 also sha 256 in my firebase console ,but still cannot login with google. I use emulator btw

Comment: Hi, also can i see the TPFirebaseUser class?